# How to open port in Amazon EC2 for Node.js Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have Node.js application that works on the port:

```
server.listen(8181);
```

So, when it works, then file socket.io should be available by path:

```
http://152.30.141.23:8181/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

But I can not get access to this file.

I tried to open ports in Security Group in Amazon console and set:

`All ICMP | Anywhere 0.0.0.0` in section inbound rules

But it does not work still.

Code is simple:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    redisServer = require('redis'),
    path = require('path'),
    time = require('time'),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8181);
```

Comment: You do not need to open an extra port for socket.io, since it (by default) uses the same port as your HTTP server. What does "can not get access to this file" mean? You received a 404 or what? Also, showing the relevant code might be beneficial since it seems to be a configuration/routing issue.

Comment: Yes, I can not get content of this file with message: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: So, when I run application, it creates server socket.io file which I try get

Comment: `All ICMP | Anywhere 0.0.0.0` will not help you, since ICMP != TCP and this is, almost certainly, a TCP socket.  You need a rule allowing inbound TCP to port 8181 from anywhere in the security group.  `Connection timed out` is exactly the error you would expect with a missing security group rule.

Comment: I tried to open TCP with port 8181, it had not helped

Comment: Also I tried to add Proxy port in Apache